# Postgresql How to Calculate between 2 date depends on another table

Tags: sql, postgresql

let's say i have two table like this :

workday_emp

```
emp_id    work_start       work_end
  1      "2021-04-06"     "2021-04-14"
  2      "2021-04-27"     "2021-05-04"
  3      "2021-04-30"     "2021-05-07"
```

holiday_tbl

```
id       name          date
1      "holiday 1"    "2021-04-07"
2      "holiday 2"    "2021-04-28"
3      "holiday 3"    "2021-04-29"
```

i want to show table like this with a query:

```
emp_id    work_start       work_end        day_holiday
  1      "2021-04-06"     "2021-04-14"          1
  2      "2021-04-27"     "2021-05-04"          2
  3      "2021-04-30"     "2021-05-07"          1
```

the question is, how to calculate how many "day_holiday" between "work_start" and "work_end" depends to "holiday_tbl" table?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Why holiday count for emp_id = 3 is 1.  It will 0 because his work_start_date is greater than holiday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this. For Employee 3 holiday count will 0 not 1 because his work_day starts at april30 but last holiday was apr29.

```
-- PostgreSQL(v11)
SELECT w.emp_id, w.work_start, w.work_end
     , (SELECT COUNT(id) 
        FROM holiday_tbl 
        WHERE holiday_date BETWEEN w.work_start AND w.work_end) day_holiday
FROM workday_emp w
```

Please check from url https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=1948691b58ba841b2765d7de383f8df8

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job:

```
SELECT emp_id, work_start, work_end, COUNT(ht.holiday) holiday_cnt
FROM workday_emp we LEFT JOIN 
(
  SELECT date holiday
  FROM holiday_tbl 
) ht ON ht.holiday BETWEEN we.work_start AND we.work_end
GROUP BY 1, 2, 3
ORDER BY 1, 2;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=9b663a0e9a5b11109a998e4a451c1791)